# How to build TF tensor with ones in specified locations - batch compatible

Tags: python, tensorflow

I apologize for the poor question title but I'm not sure quite how to phrase it. Here's the problem I'm trying to solve: I have two NNs working off of the same input dataset in my code. One of them is a traditional network while the other is used to limit the acceptable range of the first. This works by using a `tf.where()` statement which works fine in most cases, such as this toy example:

```
pcts= [0.04,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.04]
legal_actions = tf.where(pcts>=0.05, tf.ones_like(pcts), tf.zeros_like(pcts))
```

Which gives the correct result: `legal_actions = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]`

I can then multiply this by the output of my first network to limit its Q values to only those of the legal actions. In a case like the above this works great.

However, it is also possible that my original vector looks something like this, with low values in the middle of the high values: `pcts= [0.04,0.06,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.04]`

Using the same code as above my `legal_actions` comes out as this: `legal_actions = [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]`

Based on the code I have this is correct, however, I'd like to include any zeros in the middle as part of my `legal_actions`. In other words, I'd like this second example to be the same as the first. Working in basic TF this is easy to do in several different ways, such as in this reproducible example (it's also easy to do with sparse tensors):

```
import tensorflow as tf

pcts= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(10,))
legal_actions = tf.where(pcts>=0.05, tf.ones_like(pcts), tf.zeros_like(pcts))
mask = tf.where(tf.greater(legal_actions,0))
legals = tf.cast(tf.range(tf.reduce_min(mask),tf.reduce_max(mask)+1),tf.int64)

oh = tf.one_hot(legals,10)
oh = tf.reduce_sum(oh,0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(oh,feed_dict={pcts:[0.04,0.06,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.04]}))
```

The problem that I'm running into is when I try to apply this to my *actual* code which is reading in batches from a file. I can't figure out a way to fill in the "gaps" in my tensor without the range function and/or I can't figure out how to make the range function work with batches (it will only make one range at a time, not one per batch, as near as I can tell). Any suggestions on how to either make what I'm working on work or how to solve the problem a completely different way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
pcts = tf.random.uniform((2,3,4))
a = pcts>=0.5
shape = tf.shape(pcts)[-1]
a = tf.reshape(a, (-1, shape))
a = tf.cast(a, dtype=tf.float32)
def rng(t):
  left = tf.scan(lambda a, x: max(a, x), t)
  right = tf.scan(lambda a, x: max(a, x), t, reverse=True)
  return tf.minimum(left, right)

a = tf.map_fn(lambda x: rng(x), a)
a = tf.reshape(a, (tf.shape(pcts)))
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! This works great. I didn't even know about the scan function but it's exactly what I need here. Out of curiosity, the code seems to work the exact same without reshaping. What purpose does that serve here?

Comment: One other comment: this would only work for me with 'tf.maximum' instead of max in 'left' and 'right'

Comment: @cbw map_fn moves along 0 dimension, so reshaping needed here. Tried to remove reshaping - it is not working

Comment: Very odd. I tested it in my code and it works just fine without reshape. Version difference? I'm still back in the stone age running TF 1.15.